# How to edit a editable pdf form using Javascript or Java

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, pdf, editing

I want to develop a kind of software or website to help people fill in a editable pdf form. The user only need to fill in some information and I will collect the information and dynamically fill into the editable pdf form. What kind of Jar or library I need to use in this project? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) for some small toy projects and it is very easy to use and works pretty well (at least in text extraction). I tried using [iTextPDF](http://itextpdf.com/) but it didn't handle columns well.

Regarding forms, check out PDFBook's [cookbook](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/cookbook.html) where there is an example on how to set the value of a form field in a PDF.